# shell script to transfer yesterday's logfiles to a ftp server

Tags: shell, ftp, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script that will be triggered everyday and transfer yesterday's logfiles from multiple servers to a ftp server.

So far I have managed to copy them and rename them according to the naming convention (has to have YYYYMMDD in it) to another directory but not on the FTP.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

path=/home/log/
backupPath=/home/new_directory/log

if [ ! -d $backupPath ]; then
echo "$backupPath does not exist. Create it" 
mkdir $backupPath
fi;

server=$(uname -n)
for filename in $path/*string*; do    

timestamp=$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$filename")" +%Y%m%d)

basename=$(basename $filename)

newfilename=$(echo "$basename" | sed s/access/access_"$timestamp"_"$server"/g)

cp $filename $backupPath"/$newfilename"
echo "$filename moved to $backupPath/$newfilename"

done
```

Now I need to modify it to copy only yesterday's well formatted files to an FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this(not tested):

```
timestamp=$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$filename")" +%Y%m%d)

yday=$(date -d "yesterday"  +%Y%m%d)
[ "$yday" != "$timestamp" ] && continue

basename=$(basename $filename)
```

The 2 lines in the middle are to be added to your code.  The 1st line gets yesterdays date. This is then compared with the timestamp of the file. If it does not match, the file is simply skipped.

Comment: Thank you Guru! What about the FTP part?

Comment: To know how to ftp within the script, you can refer this:  http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/ftp/ftp_script_linux.htm